# Query tuning in a procedure for faster execution

Tags: performance

I have data in table1 and that is to be loaded to table2. This is being done as

```
Insert into table2 
(select a,b,c from table1 where process_dt ='28-06-2016')
```

This is taking lot of time, so to tune this are there any methods.

Comment: Please provide more details. Which Database provider etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT a,b,c INTO table2 FROM table1;
```